# What does it mean when JNA maps to the current process?

Tags: jna

In the JNA Javadoc, it says:

> The String passed to the Native.loadLibrary(String,Class) (or NativeLibrary.getInstance(String)) method is the undecorated name of the shared library file.
>
> If the library name is null, your mappings will apply to the current process instead of a separately loaded library. This may help avoid conflicts if there are several incompatible versions of a library available.

http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.4.0/javadoc/overview-summary.html#library-mapping

What does the spec mean when it says the mappings will apply to the current process?

Comment: I would guess that it means that if the currently loaded process (Java) has a library loaded in the address space, you can directly access those methods. For example, the process in which the Java program runs probably has other libraries loaded as well.